# Ошибка: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, штрихкод

Пробую пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

def testEan():
    EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
    ean = EAN(u'123456789011', writer=ImageWriter())
    fullname = ean.save('my_ean13_barcode')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testEan()
```

Получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/1.py", line 13, in <module>
    testEan()
  File "C:/Python/1.py", line 9, in testEan
    ean = EAN(u'123456789011', writer=ImageWriter())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Python 3.8 Windows10

Где этот невызываемый объект? И что ему вообще надо?

Comment: Тут сказано, что EAN  - None, то есть `barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')` ничего не вернуло

Comment: без параметра writer=ImageWriter() ошибки нет